# What is the purpose of the `Typeable (* -> Constraint) Monoid` instance?

Tags: haskell

Since GHC 7.8, `Typeable` is poly-kinded. Looking at the list of built-in `Typeable` instances [in the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#t%3aTypeable), I noticed something interesting:

```
Typeable ((* -> *) -> Constraint) Alternative
Typeable ((* -> *) -> Constraint) Applicative
Typeable (* -> Constraint) Monoid
```

Apparently, it's allowed to look at type representations of (certain) types of kind `Constraint`:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid Data.Typeable> typeRep $ (Proxy :: Proxy (Monoid Int))
Monoid Int
```

Are there any uses for this feature or was it just made available by accident?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, `ConstraintKind`s are now allowed. So this means that you can define datatypes parameterized over constraints.

A (contrived) example:

```
data CPair (c :: * -> Constraint) where
  MkCPair :: (c a, c b) => a -> b -> CPair c
```

This is a pair of two components of potentially different types that share a common class:

```
aPair :: CPair Show
aPair = MkCPair 'x' True
```

Now, do we want `aPair` to be `Typeable`? This requires both `CPair` and `Show` to
be `Typeable` as well.

```
deriving instance Typeable CPair
deriving instance Typeable Show
```

Now:

```
GHCi> typeOf aPair
CPair Show
```

So it's only consequent to derive `Typeable` for classes if they can appear as types now.

The funny thing is that `Typeable Show` isn't predefined, but `Typeable Applicative` is. This is because there's a new GHC extension `AutoDeriveTypeable` which seems to be enabled in some modules, but not in others. With `AutoDeriveTypeable`, there are `Typeable` instances being derived for everything in a module, including classes.